# String replacement using vectors

Tags: r, string

I am trying to translate certain words embedded within character strings.
I want to use a "translator" table were I set up the correspondence for the concerned word.

Here are some related posts but I was not able to find a solution from them:

- [Understanding the use of str_replace_all with multiple patterns](https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-the-use-of-str-replace-all-with-multiple-patterns/1849)
- [Replacing patterns in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999698/replacing-patterns-in-a-string)
- Others based on `str_replace_all()`, `match()` and `grep()`

Please, find below some data to work with (`mtcars` is a dataset included within R) and a piece of code that reflects the problem/question.

```
library(tidyverse)

chr_strings = rownames(mtcars) # I want to replace strings within this object

# here is the "translator" table where it is possible to establish the links between strings
trans_df = data.frame(pat = c("Mazda", "Merc", "Toyota"),
                      rep = c("Mazda corp.", "Mercedes", "Toy."), # I have intentionally used different lengths
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The goal is to replace patterns listed in `trans_df$pat` within `chr_strings` by row-corresponding patterns from `rans_df$rep`.

I have mainly tried things around this function:

```
str_replace_all(string = chr_strings, pattern = trans_df$pat, replacement = trans_df$pat) # not working
```

That produces this error:

```
Warning message:
In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It is probably a bad use of the `str_replace_all` function... Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
str_replace_all(chr_strings, setNames(trans_df$rep, trans_df$pat))

 [1] "Mazda corp. RX4"     "Mazda corp. RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710"          "Hornet 4 Drive"     
 [5] "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"             "Duster 360"          "Mercedes 240D"      
 [9] "Mercedes 230"        "Mercedes 280"
```